# PHP Regex negative look behind assertion, preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on a script for looping thru PHP files and renaming function calls when necessary. This selection needs to be done by the following rules:

- NO function declaration //function test() {
- NO static functions //SomeClass::staticMethod()
- NO class functions // $class->method()
- ONLY function calls // myFunction()

Currently I have the following regex:

```
preg_replace_callback("/((?<=function\s|\:\:|->)[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9\_]+)\(.*\)/i", 'test', $content);
```

- Function names are mostly written in camelBack notation.
- Sometimes function names contains a underscore.

This is a positive look behind assertion: it gives all the given rules classified by NO :)

So I have to change it in the negative way but that is my problem. When I try, it’s not working as proposed.

**EDIT**

When i try a negative look behind assertion

> `'?<!' instead of '?<='`

With the example above it gives the following output:

- *est() (missing first)*
- *taticMethod() (missing first)*
- *ethod() (missing first)*
- myFunction() (correct)

It drops the first letter of the functions I don't wanna match. Is there anyone who knows how to do the trick?

Comment: What is not working as proposed?

Comment: When i try a negative look behind assertion ('?<!' instead of '?<=') with the example above it gives the following output:
est(), taticMethod(), ethod(), myFunction(). 

It drops the first letter of the functions I don't wanna match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have misplaced a parenthesis. Your current regex seems to drop the first character for camelcase functions. This seems to work better (tested with a `preg_match_all`):

```
preg_match_all("/(?<=function\s|\:\:|->)([a-z][a-zA-Z0-9\_]+)\(.*\)/i", $file, $matches);
```

On a side note, you're use of `preg_replace_callback` is incorrect, since it's 2nd argument should be a `callable`

**EDIT**

As per PO's comment, my first try was dumb :)

The main problem with your expression is that if it starts with `::` it will drop out this part, but the first letter of the method name will match your first subexpression and the rest  of it will match as a method name.

I tried another approch with character groups, let me know how it works out for you:

```
preg_match_all('/[^:a-z]([a-z]+[a-zA-Z0-9\_]+)\(.*\)[^\s{]/i', $file, $matches);
```

Comment: Thank you for your improvement, but it's not working correct here. Your regex gives my the rule: "NO function declaration //function test()", but i want the following rule: "ONLY function calls // myFunction()"

On your side note: I'm using the second parameter as a reference.

Comment: Yes sorry. Editing my answer now

Comment: I implemented your regex and it seems to work perfect, thank you!