# Replace certain words with link, but exclude word that already in a link

Tags: php, regex, string

I wanted to use regex/string replace function in PHP so I can replace certain keyword with links:
Say there is a string: `

> "Hello guys I want to ask a programming questions."

The output should be

> "Hello guys I want to ask a `<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com">programming</a>` questions."

It sounds like something can be easily done with regex/string functions, however, I found out that if there is already a link in the string, like:

> "Hello guys I want to ask a `<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com">programming related</a>` questions."

The normal regex/string replace function will make it:

> "Hello guys I want to ask a `<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com"><a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com">programming</a> related</a>` questions."

Note that there is a "" inside another  tag.  What should I do so if the string, say "programming" is already in a link, it won't convert it? Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try to use negative [assertion](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php)

> **Lookbehind assertions** start with (?<= for positive assertions and (?< ! for negative assertions for negative assertions
>
> **Lookahead assertions** start with (?= for positive assertions and (?! for negative assertions

examples:

> http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-regex2/
>
> http://sabirul-mostofa.blogspot.com/2011/05/php-regex-lookaround-assertion.html
>
> [PHP Regex negative look behind assertion, preg_replace_callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904542/php-regex-negative-look-behind-assertion-preg-replace-callback)

Comment: use google, you can find many example, I will edit my answer to give you some example I found in google though.

Answer (score 0):

This would work

```
<?php
$str='Hello guys I want to ask a <a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com">programming-related</a> questions.';

$str=strip_tags($str);
$str=str_replace("programming",'<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com">programming</a>',$str);

var_dump($str);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
string(101) "Hello guys I want to ask a <a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com">programming</a>-related questions."
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your help. But I think I should not type that dash there so it kinda change programming from to another word. What if there is no dash? Just space like "programming related" inside the a tag?

Answer (score 0):

In the string replace function pass your word to be replaced with space before and after the word like this.. This may solve your problem I think

```
$str= "Hello guys I want to ask a programming questions. Hello guys I want to ask a <a href='https://www.stackoverflow.com'>programming</a> questions.";
$str=str_replace(" programming ",'<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com">programming</a>',$str);
var_dump($str);
```

**Output**

```
"Hello guys I want to ask a <a href='https://www.stackoverflow.com'>programming</a> questions. Hello guys I want to ask a <a href='https://www.stackoverflow.com'>programming</a> questions."
```

Comment: Hi, this will work in 90% but still, if there is a word like "best programming help", it would cause the same problem

Comment: If you want to replace text like "best programming help" means you can do the same for this sentence also like str_replace(" best programming help ", "your string here")

Comment: Thanks for your help man. But even if I just wanna replace "programming", it's gonna affect words like best programming help even if "best programming help" is already in an a tag.